# Ion beam deposition and high pressure phase formation

Tags: material-science, phase-transition

I'm studying some amorphous transition metal oxides (thin films) prepared by ion beam deposition. I found that the local structure of these materials is apparently characterised by properties (i.e. atomic arrangements) resembling to some extent those observed in a high-pressure crystalline phase. Unfortunately, these samples are prepared by a private company, so I cannot know the exact condiditions applied for film deposition. Anyway, from Wikipedia, I read "at a high deposition energy molecular ions fragment and atomic ions can penetrate further into the material, a process known as ion implantation". So I'm wondering if high deposition energy could somehow favour in some cases the formation of high pressure phases and, in the case, if there are references about this phenomenon.

Comment: There is 50+ years of ion beam modification of materials literature. Yes, you can often find ways to create non-equilibrium phases during ion beam deposition or ion implantation. And, yes, it is often the non-equilibrium point defect concentrations that help you end up in such a phase. One thing to do is not think of them as 'high pressure' phases, but non-equilibrium at STP - that gets you thinking more broadly.